# Need this transfinite construction reach a closed set in the absence of the Axiom of Choice? Or Hartogs' theorem?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In this question I'm primarily concerned with the workings of a set theory that lacks both Foundation and Choice.

Given a set $X$ and a function $\sigma:\mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$, we have a notion of $\sigma$-closed subset as those $A\subset X$ such that for all $B\subset A$ we have $\sigma(B)\subset A$; every subset of $B\subset X$ then has a closure as the intersection of all the closed subsets that include $B$, which I'll denote $\overline{B}$.

Potentially, there's an obvious way to assign a notion of "$\sigma$-rank" to the members of $\overline{\emptyset}$ by setting up a transfinite sequence $\gamma$ such that $\gamma_\alpha=\bigcup(\gamma``\{\beta:\beta<\alpha\})\cup\bigcup\left(\sigma``\mathcal{P}\left(\bigcup(\gamma``\{\beta:\beta<\alpha\}\right)\right)$. Once the sequence hits $\overline{\emptyset}$ it should simply start repeating, and the rank of an element in $\overline{\emptyset}$ can be taken to be the least $\alpha$ in which it is a member of $\gamma_\alpha$.

However, I am unable to persuade myself, if $X$ cannot be wellordered, that I can count on this sequence to hit $\overline{\emptyset}$. Is there a way to show that this $\gamma$ will run into this intended closed set without being able to wellorder $X$? If so, does this hold up if there is no guarantee of a wellorder that can't inject into $X$ (i.e. if Hartogs' theorem fails)?

Comment: Nice question!!

Comment: Thanks! That's high praise from you!

Comment: Don't you need to remove more than just Foundation and Choice for there to be any risk that Hartogs' theorem fails? I don't remember its proof depending on either.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Yes, the Hartog's theorem is a tangential consideration; I'm thinking about this in the context of NFU, in which Hartog's theorem fails for unrelated reasons, but it's sort of the secondary question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ZF: You can define the $\sigma$-rank of a member of $X$ as the first $\alpha$ at which it shows up in $\gamma_\alpha$ if it ever does, and $0$ otherwise. Replacement then gives you a set of all $\sigma$-ranks of members of $X$.

Every *set* of ordinals has an upper bound (due to Burali-Forti), so you can safely stop the iteration when you reach that upper bound.

The crucial fact in this construction is that the formula you plug into the Axiom of Replacement is allowed to contain *unrestricted* quantifiers over all $\alpha$. So even though the *entire* $\gamma_\alpha$ sequence does not exist as a single object, you're still allowed to ask whether there's one of the $\gamma_\alpha$ sets that contains your target element.

I'm not experienced enough with NF(U) to tell whether this argument will work there.

Comment: Only one point of clarification: As I have phrased the definition of $\gamma$, really nothing should have $\sigma$-rank 0 if the sequence reaches $\overline{\emptyset}$. But in general, I should not assume that the collection of $\sigma$-rank 0 objects is empty, correct?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: Well, if $\overline\varnothing \neq X$, then the elements outside of it would get assigned $\sigma$-rank $0$. I map them to $0$ simply to get them out of the way.

Comment: Ah, my actual puzzlement is whether everything *in* $\overline{\varnothing}$ ends up with non-zero $\sigma$-rank. Which it seems like it should, but I haven't managed to persuade myself of.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: If $\beta$ is an upper bound for all of the ranks, then there can be no new elements between $\gamma_\beta$ and $\gamma_{\beta+1}$ (because such new elements would have rank $\beta+1$, by definition). Since it is clear that the $\gamma$s are non-decreasing, we must have $\gamma_\beta=\gamma_{\beta+1}$ -- or in other words, $\gamma_\beta$ is closed, so it contains $\overline\varnothing$.

Comment: Ack. Now I just feel silly. :P Thanks!

Comment: (And as a side note, I think this works fine in NF(U) if every wellorderable subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is isomorphic to a proper initial segment of the ordinals. Though it's hard to say how big is too big for this to hold...)